# How to define a constant?

Tags: php, constants

I'm using WP Super Cache on my shop site, and it doesn't let shopcart update after we add item or remove them. On internet, someone said that I need to define a constant called DONOTCACHEPAGE (only on that shopcart page). But I don't have any idea about "define a constant", and I don't know much about PHP too. Anyone here can help me step by step about this?

Comment: It *doesn't*, not "it don't." http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

For example

```
define ('BASE_URI', 'C:\xampp\\');
```

Comment: I already see many walkthrough like that. But the thing is that I don't know how to start. I must open a file and add those code, or what?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin. Have you tried the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ site

Comment: I want to ask to know more about PHP, not just to deal with this problem, that's why i'm come here :)

Comment: Well you are in the right place. That's how you define a constant in PHP, how the plugin works in relation I don't know.

Comment: I know that i need to put the code, but where is to put it? For example, to change a style, I have a style.css file. And how about PHP, also add codes into files?

Comment: Inside the plugin in wordpress, there is a way to view the plugin php files. If the solution would be to use a constant it will be in one of those files.

Comment: If the right code is "define('DONOTCACHEPAGE',1);" and the page ID is 13 for example, then what is exactly the full code that I need to put?

Comment: I can't guarentee what the right code is. But from what you say you need to find a file called cart or shoppingcart.php and add define('DONOTCACHEPAGE',1); to it. The cart page will be the same for every page ID I suspect

Comment: Ok thanks, i will come to wordpress stack to ask more about this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put this line in the declarations part of the code:

```
define('DONOTCACHEPAGE',1);
```

Comment: Can you please tell where is exactly the place that i need to put this code? Where is "the declarations part of the code"? And the number "1" is page ID, right?

Comment: The number 1 is true in PHP